# Improve Fortran computation-time

Tags: performance, optimization, memory-management, fortran

I have this snippet of code I implemented at first to be checked. After check, I am now wondering if it could be optimised. In particular, the question that raised is:

"Would it be better to pre-initialise all single members of that big computation instead of computing them directly inside it (i.e. sqrt() ) ?"

In other words, would it exist a trade-off between memory allocation vs. CPU time in executing calculation within calculation themselves ?

here it is the code snippet (EDIT):

```
                                 do id=1,3
                                    BF(idx1,idx2,idx3)  = BF(idx1,idx2,idx3) +&
                                       ! i-j, i-k
                                       2*bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,4+id,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,1+id,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,1+id,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(id,p1)* sqrt(SU(i1,id,inode)*SU(i1,id,jnode))) * (nodCorr(id,p2)* sqrt(SU(i2,id,inode)*SU(i2,id,knode)) )+&
                                       ! i-j, j-k
                                       2*bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,1+id,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,4+id,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,1+id,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(id,p1)* sqrt(SU12(id,inode)*SU12(id,jnode))) * (nodCorr(id,p3)* sqrt(SU(i2,id,jnode)*SU(i2,id,knode)) )+&
                                       ! i-k, j-k
                                       2*bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,1+id,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,1+id,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,4+id,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(id,p2)* sqrt(SU12(id,inode)*SU12(id,knode))) * (nodCorr(id,p3)* sqrt(SU(i1,id,jnode)*SU(i1,id,knode)) )
                                 enddo

                                 ! dir 1-2
                                 BF(idx1,idx2,idx3)  = BF(idx1,idx2,idx3) +&
                                    ! i-k, i-j
                                    bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,8,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,3,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,2,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(1,p2)* sqrt( SU(i2,1,inode)*SU(i2,1,knode) )) * (nodCorr(2,p1)* sqrt( SU(i1,2,inode)*SU(i1,2,jnode) ) )+&
                                    ! i-j, j-k
                                    bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,2,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,8,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,3,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(1,p2)* sqrt( SU12(1,inode)*SU12(1,jnode) )) * (nodCorr(2,p3)* sqrt( SU(i2,2,jnode)*SU(i2,2,knode) ) )+&
                                    ! j-k, i-k
                                    bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,3,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,2,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,8,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(1,p3)* sqrt( SU(i1,1,jnode)*SU(i1,1,knode) )) * (nodCorr(2,p2)* sqrt( SU12(2,inode)*SU12(2,knode) ) )+&
                                    ! i-j, i-k
                                    bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,8,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,2,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,3,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(1,p1)* sqrt( SU(i1,1,inode)*SU(i1,1,jnode) )) * (nodCorr(2,p2)* sqrt( SU(i2,2,inode)*SU(i2,2,knode) ) )+&
                                    ! j-k, i-j
                                    bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,3,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,8,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,2,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(1,p3)* sqrt( SU(i2,1,jnode)*SU(i2,1,knode) )) * (nodCorr(2,p1)* sqrt( SU12(2,inode)*SU12(2,jnode) ) )+&
                                    ! i-k, j-k
                                    bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,2,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,3,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,8,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(1,p2)* sqrt( SU12(1,inode)*SU12(1,knode) )) * (nodCorr(2,p3)* sqrt( SU(i1,2,jnode)*SU(i1,2,knode) ) )

                                 
                                 ! dir 1-3
                                 BF(idx1,idx2,idx3)  = BF(idx1,idx2,idx3) +&
                                    ! i-k, i-j
                                    bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,9,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,4,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,2,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(1,p2)* sqrt( SU(i2,1,inode)*SU(i2,1,knode) )) * (nodCorr(3,p1)* sqrt( SU(i1,3,inode)*SU(i1,3,jnode) ) )+&
                                    ! i-j, j-k
                                    bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,2,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,9,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,4,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(1,p2)* sqrt( SU12(1,inode)*SU12(1,jnode) )) * (nodCorr(3,p3)* sqrt( SU(i2,3,jnode)*SU(i2,3,knode) ) )+&
                                    ! j-k, i-k
                                    bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,4,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,2,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,9,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(1,p3)* sqrt( SU(i1,1,jnode)*SU(i1,1,knode) )) * (nodCorr(3,p2)* sqrt( SU12(3,inode)*SU12(3,knode) ) )+&
                                    ! i-j, i-k
                                    bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,9,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,2,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,4,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(1,p1)* sqrt( SU(i1,1,inode)*SU(i1,1,jnode) )) * (nodCorr(3,p2)* sqrt( SU(i2,3,inode)*SU(i2,3,knode) ) )+&
                                    ! j-k, i-j
                                    bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,4,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,9,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,2,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(1,p3)* sqrt( SU(i2,1,jnode)*SU(i2,1,knode) )) * (nodCorr(3,p1)* sqrt( SU12(3,inode)*SU12(3,jnode) ) )+&
                                    ! i-k, j-k
                                    bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,2,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,4,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,9,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(1,p2)* sqrt( SU12(1,inode)*SU12(1,knode) )) * (nodCorr(3,p3)* sqrt( SU(i1,3,jnode)*SU(i1,3,knode) ) )


                                 ! dir 2-3
                                 BF(idx1,idx2,idx3)  = BF(idx1,idx2,idx3) +&
                                    bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,10,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,4,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,3,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(2,p2)* sqrt( SU(i2,2,inode)*SU(i2,2,knode) )) * (nodCorr(3,p1)* sqrt( SU(i1,3,inode)*SU(i1,3,jnode) ) )+&
                                    bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,3,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,10,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,4,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(2,p2)* sqrt( SU12(2,inode)*SU12(2,jnode) )) * (nodCorr(3,p3)* sqrt( SU(i2,3,jnode)*SU(i2,3,knode) ) )+&
                                    bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,4,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,3,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,10,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(2,p3)* sqrt( SU(i1,2,jnode)*SU(i1,2,knode) )) * (nodCorr(3,p2)* sqrt( SU12(3,inode)*SU12(3,knode) ) )+&
                                    bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,10,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,3,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,4,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(2,p1)* sqrt( SU(i1,2,inode)*SU(i1,2,jnode) )) * (nodCorr(3,p2)* sqrt( SU(i2,3,inode)*SU(i2,3,knode) ) )+&
                                    bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,4,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,10,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,3,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(2,p3)* sqrt( SU(i2,2,jnode)*SU(i2,2,knode) )) * (nodCorr(3,p1)* sqrt( SU12(3,inode)*SU12(3,jnode) ) )+&
                                    bsa_wind_coeff(ilib,3,inode)*bsa_wind_coeff(jlib,4,jnode)*bsa_wind_coeff(klib,10,knode)* &
                                       (nodCorr(2,p2)* sqrt( SU12(2,inode)*SU12(2,knode) )) * (nodCorr(3,p3)* sqrt( SU(i1,3,jnode)*SU(i1,3,knode) ) )
```

Some NOTES:

*bsa_wind_coeffs* is a Common Variable (declared in a Module), while all others present in the code snippet are passed directly (i.e. I assume a copy is created locally). Within the procedure itself, indexes *ilib, jlib, klib, inode, jnode, knode* are looped. This computation is called many time within an external procedure.

EDIT:
all variables in here are **static** in the sense that they're computed once (before calling this procedure) and then just walked based on some indexes values as you can see. That is, at each call, same arrays are passed.

Comment: Without a minimal full example it is hard to tell, important would also be the loops around (steering the indices) and some information about the size, data type of the variables etc.

Comment: @albert, loops (where possible of course) are already optimised to go column-wise. Data type (in the operation itself) is always *real* (8 bytes). Size can vary, but I would say it does not cange the question.
My question wants to be more "*conceptual*", that is, if there exists a threshold before which this implementation could be preferred w.r.t. the opposite (pre initialise all member in tmp vars).

Comment: `sqrt` calculations are quite expensive so it might be be useful to store the results in a temporary array but all depends on the number of calls with the same input arrays of which `sqrt` is taken, size of the extra memory required, possibility to keep parts in the internal caches ....

Comment: Basically I agree with Albert - without a minimal but complete example it's hard to say a lot except it looks like application of a stencil, so I would try to minimise the work at each point on the grid by calculating outside the inner loop(s) as much as is possible, especially sqrts. But ouch, this code hurts my eyes! The very first thing I would do is break it down to a number of more simple statements, rather than one huge, monolithic, confusing thing.

Comment: It's really hard to see what's going on in that code. Can I suggest you have a loop over at least the `dir` indices, rather than writing them all out. (You should be able to tell the compiler to unroll loops if adding loops hits the performance). And even without pre-calculating the `sqrt()` parts, you can use `sqrt(a*b)=sqrt(a)*sqrt(b)` to reduce the number of `sqrt` calculations required. The compiler might be doing this anyway, but it will make things easier to read.

Comment: @veryreverie regarding the `sqrt(a*b)=sqrt(a)*sqrt(b)` might this not give different results when a and be are of a complete different magnitude?

Comment: @albert I'm no expert in floating point, but I don't think so? If `da` and `db` are small errors, then `(a+da)*(b+db) = a*b*(1+da/a+db/b)` and `sqrt(a+da) = sqrt(a)(1+da/2a)` so both functions are quite well behaved w/r/t error propogation, so I think the order should be interchangeable?

Comment: @IanBush I made some edits to the code to make it more readable. Hope this makes it easier to follow.

Comment: @veryreverie I'm not an expert in floating point computations, but when the assumption is that the terms of the sqrt are small it might happen that a*b is smaller than what fits into a floating point number and is giving a 0 are a NaN or .. so also sqrt gives a number according. with sqrt(a)*sqrt(b) are calculated first and will give "reasonable" numbers as will the product from the multiplication of the sqrt. Also note that it would be better to use (also probably in the original) an absolute value or is it guaranteed that a and b are positive. All this probably outside the scope here.

Comment: @albert Ah, yep, you're right and I'm wrong. Very small numbers are a problem.

Comment: @albert what's inside `sqrt ()` is proven to be always positive.

Comment: @mEm both terms positive or the multiplication?

Comment: @albert, both, by consequence their multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments you say you want a "conceptual" answer as to when pre-computing is faster than not pre-computing.

Unfortunately, making a static analysis of which of two methods is better is often difficult, for a couple of reasons. Firstly, optimising compilers are very clever, and do a lot of fairly unpredictable things behind the scenes. Secondly, there are a lot of external variables, and the details of the compiler, the cpu, the memory etc. will change the results.

The answer to the question "which of these two algorithms is faster" is usually "try both and see". You should at least time your code, but using a profiling tool is ideal. Not only will a profiling tool tell you how long the different approaches take, it will help narrow down what parts of the two approaches are taking the most time. This lets you know which parts of the code you should optimise for the best results.

Comment: Not just that *compilers* are complex and clever, but modern *CPUs* with out-of-order exec to hide latency of cache misses and computations.  And that multi-level CPU caches with hardware prefetching are also complex.  So ideally you'd test on a couple different kinds of CPUs, especially if the results are close on one.